# Перезагрузка сцены

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как перезагрузить сцену чтобы в скриптах все переменные очистились?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точно также, как вы просто переходите на сцену. Например, [SceneManager.LoadScene()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html). Получится, что сцена выгрузится и загрузится на чистую

Comment: я так пробовал но переменные с теми же значениями что и после перезагрузки!

Comment: Тут так ещё получается, что при первой загрузки всё нормально а при последующей всё плохо

Comment: @AimonZ. в Start() может выписать начальные данные переменных, если при перезапуске сцены переменные не меняются.